# php prepared statement SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, syntax-error, prepared-statement

I am trying to change to prepared statements but keep getting the following error:

**Warning: PDO::query(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an 
   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':fname AND**

Here is the code im using:

```
$street = 'astreet';
$lname = 'alname';
$fname = 'afname';
$list = '1,2,3,4,5';

   $var = 'admin';  

   $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=customers;host=localhost",$var,$var);

   $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` in ($list) AND `first_name` LIKE :fname AND `last_name` LIKE :lname AND `street_name` LIKE :street";

   $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

   $stmt->execute(array(':street' => $street));
   $stmt->execute(array(':fname' => $fname));
   $stmt->execute(array(':lname' => $lname));

   $result = $db->query($sql);



foreach ($result as $row) {

        echo $row['post_code'];

              }
```

if I run the query as normal - not a prepared staement, it works fine - its only when I start adding the **:variables** to the query I get the error

Is there any code missing/incorrect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute(array(':street' => $street));
$stmt->execute(array(':fname' => $fname));
$stmt->execute(array(':lname' => $lname));
```

You're running the same query three times, with a different parameter each time. You need to run the query as so:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute(array(':street' => $street, ':fname' => $fname, ':lname' => $lname));
```

And pass all three parameters in one go.

Edited to add:

You can also try binding the parameters explicitly:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':street', $street);
$stmt->bindParam(':fname', $fname);
$stmt->bindParam(':lname', $lname);

$stmt->execute();
```

Or adding them as an array:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` in ($list) AND `first_name` LIKE ? AND `last_name` LIKE ? AND `street_name` LIKE ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute(array($fname, $lname, $street));
```

Comment: @asdf1234 - I've added a couple more suggestions

Comment: thanks but these still did not work - same error plus Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @asdf1234 - you're getting the same error from the third one? That doesn't include the string `:fname` at all.

Comment: same error code but for the question mark:

MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?

Comment: That's intriguing. I'd guess that there's something up with your SQL, but it looks perfect - the field and table names are all quoted correctly. Can you try adding a `var_dump($stmt->ErrorInfo())` and `var_dump($db->ErrorInfo())` just before the execute, to see if they produce anything interesting? Also, I assume you get a similar error if you swap around the WHERE clause so `lname` is first?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to escape strings in SQL.
So I would replace

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` in ($list) AND `first_name` LIKE :fname AND `last_name` LIKE :lname AND `street_name` LIKE :street";
```

by

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` in ($list) AND `first_name` LIKE ':fname' AND `last_name` LIKE ':lname' AND `street_name` LIKE ':street' ";
```

Comment: Note this is quoting strings, not escaping them. Also, prepared statement parameters not only don't need to be quoted, they shouldn't be quoted, as they aren't values but placeholders for values. Think of the parameters like function parameters.

Comment: @outis - yes, you are absolutely correct. thanks for clarification.